# how to return a draggable item to its initial position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, droppable

I have a set of images placed as `position:relative` (showing one next to the other).

I use this code to drag and drop them (stolen from the jQuery API documentation, modified to my needs).

```
$(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    // Show start dragged position of image.
                    var Startpos = $(this).offset();
                    $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
                    pos_left = Startpos.left; //pos_left is global
                    pos_top = Startpos.top; //pos_top is also global
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    // Show dropped position.
                    var Stoppos = $(this).offset();
                    $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
                    $(this).css('position', "fixed"); //tried absolute and relative, too
                    $(this).css('left', pos_left);
                    $(this).css('top', pos_top); 
                }
        });

        $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                   id = $(this).attr('id');    
               alert(id);
            }
        });
    });
```

What I am trying to do is to return the draggable element to its initial position, after user drops it. However because my elements are relatively positioned the initial left,top coords are the same for all of them (or this is what I understand from the documentation -- I might be wrong here). So although images return, they actually stack each one on top of the other.

What am I doing wrong? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Did you try position relative with left and top set to 0px?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well. Instead of doing that by yourself use the revert option of the draggable. From the jQuery UI docks:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ revert: true });
```

Comment: Thanks. This is also a good point. However I need to return elements in their initial position but not always. Can I do that, too)?

Comment: When do you want them to be returned and when to not be returned?

Comment: when the draggable does not drop exactly onto the droppable I want it to be returned.

Comment: Then you can use $( ".selector" ).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

Answer (score 1):

You could make its position relative, top=0px, and left=0px.  Worked for me with this code:

```
$(function(){
$('#draggable').draggable().append('<a href=# class=exit>x</a>');
});
$(function(){
$('.exit').click(function(){
$('#draggable').css({
'top': '0px',
'left': '0px',
'position': 'relative'
});
});
});
```